# Python script need help adding an export .txt into it

Tags: python, export

```
f = open('f.txt', 'r')
import re

for line in f:
    u = line.split(':')[0]
    p = line.split(':')[1]
    m = re.search(r'\d+$', u)

    if m is not None:
        m1 = re.search(r'\d+',p)
        if m1 is None:
            print(u + ':' + p.rstrip() + m.group())
f.close()

f = open('f.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    l = line.rstrip().split(':')[1]
    m = re.search(r'\d+', l)
    if m is None:
        print(line.rstrip() + '123')
f.close()

f = open('f.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    l = line.rstrip().split(':')[1]
    m = re.search(r'\d+', l)
    if m is None:
        print(line.rstrip() + '1')
f.close()

f = open('f.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    u = line.split(':')[0]
    p = line.split(':')[1]
    m = re.search(r'\d+$', u)

    if m is not None and len(m.group()) == 4:
        if int(m.group()) < 2013 and int(m.group()) > 1950:
            m1 = re.search(r'\d+$',p)
            if m1 is None:
                print(u + ':' + p.rstrip() + m.group()[2:])
f.close()

f = open('f.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    s = line.split(':')[1]
    m = re.search(r'\d+', s)

    if m is not None:
        newone = line.split(':')[0] + ':' + re.sub(r'\d+',"", s).rstrip()
        if newone[-1:] != ':':
            print(line.split(':')[0] + ':' + re.sub(r'\d+',"", s).rstrip())
f.close()
```

this is my .py scrit I had made, It works fine but it doesnt export a .txt once it has finished editing all of the lines in f.txt - it just closes

Could I get some help in adding some code to make it export as finished.txt - thanks in advance

Comment: Which part of this script seems broken to you?

Comment: Where do you file.write ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not opening a file in writing mode in any part of the code.

You do it like this:

```
e = open('filename.txt', 'w')
```

Then, write lines to it:

```
e.write('example string')
```